# What would it take for earth to have a perpetual layer of clouds, making impossible to see the surface from space?

Tags: earth-like

And what would the consequences of this massive be? I assume heat would drop to an extent at the least, right? And less UV light for plants?

Comment: Plants do not use UV light, at all. Plants use visible light only. And most of them won't be happy *at all* with a perpetually overcast sky. Plant growth will be massively slowed down. Everybody dies of starvation. Sad.

Comment: I think that in one of the episode of Cosmos Carl Sagan discuss this from the second end. So what were the speculation about the reson some planets in our solar system are covered with gas/clouds.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need conditions similair to venus. With high temperatures in the lower and upper regions of the atmosphere with an incredibly cold layer in between, so that any rain that condensates within the clouds will vaporise before it even hits the ground.